# Is there anywhere I can see the code for the Napili Template Custom Layout Types?

Tags: custom, napili, page-layout, type, facet

I'm really wanting to see the Napili Template code for a number of reasons, that would REALLY help me out. I'm wanting to see how to:

- Get the "company logo" from the "branding" section of the community builder
- Same with the "header image"
- Get the footer section to work in a custom layout
- mimic the look of the header

If anyone knows how I can clone or view the code of the Napili template "Home" or "Inner" Layout Types - I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: We also had requirement to display different logo based on which customer logged in. So, we unchecked the display Header and Search component that displays and placed our own custom header component and in that we display the company logo of the customer who logged in. I guess same thing is possible for footer also. We also created our own Search component display on the home page.

Comment: Could you provide any details on how you did that? How are you putting in the logo? Is it just hard-coded? 


Also, when you're doing the custom search component did you write a completely custom search, or just change how the default search is being displayed?


Any details would be greatly appreciated!!